# Altering item data from store_order_item_add hooks (_start or _end)

Tags: expresso-store, hook

I'm not sure if is deliberate, but the way hooks have been implemented in Exp:resso Store don't seem to allow the modification of data?

Using pass by reference has no effect (because of EE's hook calling approach?); any changes made to the data passed in the params is not available in the same variables in the hook calling method.

And there doesn't seem to be any point returning data from the extension method because there is no assignment in the Order model's addItem method, where the hook is called.

Are the hooks designed to expose data for reading-only? If I have to start hacking the Store logic code to add an assignment, or messing about modifying the records in the database, then the likelihood of functionality breaking with an update is high.

I'm disappointed this type of situation wasn't envisioned by the module developers. Why limit the hooks like this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have often used `store_order_item_add_end` to modify product attributes. `$item` is an object, and pass by reference does indeed work in this context.

So this code in your extension should change every item's price to $20:

```
$item->price = '20.00';
```

I have several sites doing this for items which I have javascript-driven price configurations for, and for which I want to confirm server-side to protect from being artificially modified in the browser.

Comment: Thanks, Derek! FWIW, Tom, Derek's suggestion worked great for me in a quick test when I switched over to using `store_order_item_add_end` instead of `store_order_item_add_start` -- having access to `$item` was what I was missing in my tests.

Comment: I was trying to modify the contents of the $item_attributes param, which I tried altering to pass by reference (had no effect). I also tried to access the $order->items array in the store_order_item_add_end hook, but strangely this wasn't defined. I'd presumed that since $item had already been added to the $order->items array in the addItem logic flow (before the store_order_item_add_end hook was called), that it was too late to change the contents of $item. Really wish the documentation was better for the hooks - not just "read the module code to figure these out"!

Answer (score 0):

What Store hook are you using? You can definitely modify Store data using an extension. Did you try using `$order->save()` ?

For example

```
public function store_order_complete_start($order)
{   

    // Save some custom data on the order
    $order->order_custom4 = $my_custom_data;
    $order->save();

    return $order;
}
```

Comment: store_order_item_add_start or store_order_item_add_end - i.e. the item is not yet part of the order, or in the database. store_order_complete_start  looks like an order completion hook (so the data is in the db already).

Comment: Ah, right. You said that in the title of your question. :-P I haven't made use of those hooks before myself and in a few quick tests I wasn't able to get anywhere. Sorry I can't be of more help, but I bet someone with more experience in that area will chime in here on using those hooks. You might get better help if you update your question with sample code and more info about your specific goals.

Comment: Derek's answer hopefully gets you where you need to go, at least with the store_order_item_add_end hook.